# Simple addition and subtraction for tuples of X and Y coordinates

Tags: python

I have been studying Python for about 6 months now, and although I have a lot of factual knowledge, I still have very little experiential programming knowledge (in Python or otherwise). As a result, I'm concerned that 1. I am reinventing the wheel and 2. my attempts at solving my problem on my own are going to be fraught with issues I am not aware of.

### Problem

The problem is simple. I have points composed of X and Y coordinates. I want to be able to simply add and subtract them together and test for equality:

```
a = Point(1,1)
b = Point(2,2)
assert a + a == b
```

An added difficulty is I have at least two different **kinds** of points, and I need to be able to convert between them and test for coordinate equality between them as well:

```
r = RegularPoint(1,1)
i = InterfacePoint(1,1)
ri = RegularPoint(i)
assert ri == i
```

These types of points are "exactly the same" animals, I just need to be able to differentiate between them.

Some more possibly relevant information: multiple object references to the points will be held in many containers, and there will only be tens of thousands of them at most.

### Solution attempt

I have tried using `collections.namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple as nt
PointA = nt('PointA','x y')
PointB = nt('PointB','x y')
```

This is nice because testing for equality of the two different types of points is trivial, and "converting" works too:

```
a = PointA(1,1)
b = PointB(1,1)
assert a == b
aB = PointB(*a)
assert aB == a
```

But my test code will fail because adding `tuple`s together behaves differently than the desired result:

```
assert a + a == (1, 1, 1, 1)
```

How can I get this working the way I want? I am not married to this approach at all, by the way, so tell me to throw it away completely if that's the best thing.

### Other options I have considered

- Independently implement the behavior by writing my `Point` classes, which doesn't seem ***too*** hard - but I feel like I'd be reinventing a wheel that has surely been created millions of times.
- Use an abstract base class and just provide the requisite methods - perhaps `numbers.Complex`
- use a `numpy.matrix` (or `array`) for the points

Comment: "vector" might be a useful keyword in your research on this topic. That's one typical name for a class that handles spatial coordinates, and which can usually be added, subtracted, etc.

Comment: thanks. my question got closed faster than any question i've ever seen! i guess it was too broad. :( Too bad because I really need help on this.

Comment: Read up on NumPy. A `numpy` `array` (not `matrix`) is definitely the best way to go, and storing your points together as a `numpy` `array` is also probably the way to go.

Comment: While I am not sure this answers your question directly, you can add the methods to your namedtuple class by inheriting from it: `class Point(namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])):` and adding an `__add__` method

Comment: FWIW, [here](https://gist.github.com/kms70847/3d03a226f6228ee69f4b) is the `Point` class that I wrote for my own geometry experiments. This might give you some ideas, or you could even just copy it wholesale and staple a `kind` attribute to it.

Comment: I have attempted to edit the question so it is no longer off-topic. Not sure why it's still on hold. I described the problem and a specific solution attempt to solve it that isn't working.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. I believe closing in the first place was a mistake - this question isn't just asking for a resource. There's a problem and an attempt at a solution, with an acknowledgement that a better solution may already exist as a library (and requests for the link if it does exist.)

Comment: Generally speaking, with regards to (1), no matter what wheel you need to create, it's almost a given any more that at least the hub of that wheel already exists somewhere (whether it's available and accessible to the public is an entirely different matter) - there's very little that is genuinely new in programming any more. And regarding (2), the best answer to that is just experience/practice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how to implement addition in a new class called `Point`:

```
class Point(namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

You want a bit more than just a `namedtuple`, because you're doing more than just storing data. So I wrap that in a new class called `Point`. That new class needs to implement binary addition via `+`, which in Python is done by implementing a `__add__` method.

[Kevin's code on GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/kms70847/3d03a226f6228ee69f4b) could be useful if you want to see how to implement a more flexible Point class that can handle more than just 2 dimensions.

Comment: Any reason to prefer this approach over using `numpy.array`?

Comment: I believe the `Point` class that you linked actually came from Kevin in the comments. @RickTeachey many users don't have `numpy`, if nothing else! :)

Comment: What about inheriting from both `namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])` AND one of the abc's in `numbers`? That way I can be sure I am providing all the methods I need, and I get some for free.

Comment: Maybe not - I guess I wouldn't want outside code to confuse my `Point`s with types of numbers (e.g, `isinstance(mypoint,numbers.Number)`).

Comment: Adam, you're right. Both Kevin and Iain made helpful comments from which I put together the code for my answer - I've edited the answer to mention that it's Kevin's code on GitHub Gist, not Iain's. Rick, I wouldn't inherit from `number` because a `Point` is not a `number`, even if they have some method names in common. I'm not familiar with `numpy` so I couldn't say why to use it or avoid it (I certainly hear about it a lot, but most of the code I write in Python isn't about number crunching, so I've never needed to use it). Anyways, if this answer is what you want, you should accept it.

Comment: Not sure if it's what I want or not. Still tinkering.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I ended up doing. The numpy suggestion was a good one but I felt that I really wanted to have more control over what this class is able to do.

Comment: @RickTeachey: Glad to hear I helped.